# Adding anchor tag class breaks the link

Tags: html, css, wordpress, anchor

I'm trying to help out a friend add a anchor-tag class to [this page](http://www.accessphysicaltherapywellness.com/wellness-2/) so that the anchor links jump to the top of the section. Without a class, only a few of the links go to the spot I'd like them to go to.

When I try to add an anchor tag class (see below) that I've used on several other sites, the links break and no longer jump anywhere on the page.

```
.anchor-tag {
   position: absolute!important;
   display: block!important;
   visibility: hidden!important;
   top: -30px!important;
}
```

I am currently using this for the link:

```
    <a href="#Woodstock">Woodstock Fitness Studio"</a>
```

and this for the anchor point:

```
    <a name="Woodstock" class="anchor-tag"></a>
```

The page is entirely made up of shortcodes (not my doing) so I'm not sure if that's why it's not working, but I can't see to find out what is causing the links not to work when I apply the class. For now, I only have the class applied to the Woodstock link.

Comment: You're positioning the anchor at -30px , so the page should be scrolling to the top of the page when that href link is clicked.  Is that not happening? Or is that not what you intend to happen? (And if the latter, what *do* you intend?  It's not clear to me why you'd position these anchors offscreen)

Comment: The link's name is `Woodstock`, not its `id`

Comment: ah that's also true, `name` changed to `id` in html5, I always forget that. `name` still seems to work (at least in desktop safari), but perhaps not universally...

Comment: Whoops, sorry that was a typo... I meant margin-top not just top. What I intend to happen is that the links will jump to the different section further down the page, but that is not happening. I've tried wrapping the section in a div, deleting the <a name> and using the div as the anchor, but no luck there either.